Equation of an ellipse based on a point on the major axis
I need confirmation that my method of revising the standard equation of an ellipse is correct.  Per the drawing below, P is a point on the major axis (P is not necessarily the focus of an ellipse) and O is the center of the ellipse.  The standard equation of an ellipse is
$$\frac{x^2}{a^2} +\frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$$
From the point, P, the components of a line of length p drawn to an arbitrary point, M, on the ellipse are
$$x_p = x + w$$
or
$$x = x_p-w$$
and
$$y_p = y$$
The polar coordinates are
$$x_p = p\cos\phi$$
$$y_p = p\sin\phi$$
Plugging these equations into the standard equation of an ellipse yields
$$\frac{(x_p-w)^2}{a^2} +\frac{y_p^2}{b^2} = 1$$
and further
$$\frac{(p\cos\phi-w)^2}{a^2} +\frac{(p\sin\phi)^2}{b^2} = 1$$
Now, this should work for any point, P, on the major axis.  Is that correct?


Everything looks correct.

Thank you for taking the time.
